# How to convert String null value into BigDecimal in java

Tags: type-conversion

Can any one help me on , How to convert String null value into BigDecimal.

Below is the code

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class StringToBigDecimal {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String val= "";

    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(val);

    System.out.println(bigDecimal);
}
```

}

output:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException

Thanks in advance
Manju

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option, use Optionals:

```
String val= "";

Optional<BigDecimal> bigDecimal = Optional.of(val)))
        .map(BigDecimal::new)
        .map(BigDecimal::abs);
```